# Flutter Driver: Test file not found

Tags: flutter, testing, integration

I'm attempting to run `flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart` and I get the error:

```
Target file "test_driver/app.dart" not found.
```

So I changed the path to `flutter drive --target=lib/test_driver/app.dart` and I get the error:

```
Using device sdk gphone x86 arm.
Test file not found: /home/user/Documents/dev/flutter-app/test_driver/test_driver/app_test.dart.
```

This is my project structure:

```
flutter-app/
  lib/
    test_driver/
      app.dart
      app_test.dart
```

Why can't it locate the test file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter driver expects the `test_driver` directory to be a direct child of the project's root directory. So I moved it outside of `lib/` and that fixed the issue.